# How does pickle create an instance in defiance of the constructor?

Tags: python, pickle

My ultimate goal is to have a class that has a regular constructor, but also a second constructor that can be used to create partially instantiated versions of the class.

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self, foo, bar):
      self.foo = foo
      self.bar = bar
   def create_partial(self, **kwargs):
      self.foo = kwargs.get('foo', None)
      self.bar = kwargs.get('bar', None)
```

I noticed that pickle achieves this somehow. You can write `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` functions that only deal with one of the parameters and it ignores the fact you haven't defined one of them. For example

```
class Foo(object):
  def__init__(self, foo, bar):
    self.foo = foo
    self.bar = bar
  def __getstate__(self):
    return {'foo': self.foo}
  def __setstate__(self, d):
    self.foo = d['foo']
```

Then I can pickle and unpickle an instance to get a semi instantiated object

```
myfoo = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(Foo(1,2)))
print(myfoo.foo) # 1
print(myfoo.bar) # throws AttributeError
type(myfoo) # __main__.Foo
```

So, my question is, how does it manage to get a blank instance of the class, half instantiate it and have it still report its type as Foo, further, how can I do the same without having to go through pickle?

P.S. I know this is an insane thing to **want** to do, but I want to know how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `Foo()`, we think of this as calling `Foo.__init__()`. But really, there's an additional step before that, which creates the object. `foo = Foo(a, b, c)` is roughly equivalent to

```
foo = Foo.__new__(Foo, a, b, c)
foo.__init__(a, b, c)
```

[`__new__`](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#construction) is a rarely-used magic method that actually *constructs* the object. You almost never need to override it (the most common use case for overriding it is when subclassing builtin types like `float`), and most classes inherit the default `object.__new__`. We can call that latter function directly.

```
# Assuming that Foo doesn't override __new__
myfoo = Foo.__new__(Foo)
# Or, to be extra safe
myfoo = object.__new__(Foo)
```

Note that `__new__` takes the intended type as the first parameter, so even though we call `object.__new__`, we still get a `Foo` since we passed `Foo` as the parameter. No constructors were harmed in the process.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `Foo.__new__(Foo)` to create your object without going through `__init__`.